# How does ModelBuilder compare with Vensim and Stella for environmental modeling?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, modelling, environmental-monitoring, limitations

Does anyone have any advice or has anyone experienced any limitations in ArcGIS software when trying to use model builder for any type of environmental phenomenon? I know that [Vensim](http://www.vensim.com/documentation/index.html?sample_models.htm) and [Stella](http://www.iseesystems.com/softwares/Education/StellaSoftware.aspx) can be used with more detail for just about anything when modeling an environmental phenomenon. What kind of limitations might there be with ArcGIS software?

Comment: Your question is way too broad, what type of "environmental phenomenon" are you talking about? What are venism and stella?

Comment: Any type of modeling that includes an effect to the environment.

Comment: They are both modeling software systems. Vensim: http://www.vensim.com/documentation/index.html?sample_models.htm  http://vensim.com/vensim-software/   Stella: http://www.iseesystems.com/softwares/Education/StellaSoftware.aspx

Comment: I think what Dan C meant was you need to give us more details as to what you are looking for in order for us to give a good answer.  Do you mean is ArcGIS realistically too slow to make running XYZ modeling processes possible using near real-time data?  Do you mean does ArcGIS have tools to perform XYZ analysis (Ex: are there tools to model changes to river channels based on area elevation changes effecting water flow), etc...  We need some specifics or some direction where to go with this question.

Comment: Basically, I was just asking if anyone has experienced any limitations with model builder. That is all.

Comment: ModelBuilder has *many* limitations. You need to be much more specific. List examples of use cases that you are familiar with and what limitations you are concerned about.

Comment: When doing any type of environmental modeling. When doing Environmental modeling with Stella, you can do hydrologic models, temperature controls, economics, homeostasis, exponential growth with population, harvesting, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what type of environmental monitoring you are doing.  However, most of the work I do in that field is raster-based, which brings up a host of issues when ArcGIS is limited to ModelBuilder:

1. There is poor control of raster bit depth.
2. There is limited string manipulation capabilities, which is
   important for renaming/redefining files, paths, and workspaces.
3. Many of the ArcGIS raster-based analysis tools are black boxes (i.e.
   you just have to trust that they have the algorithm correct and implemented properly).
4. There is no real support for parallel processing for large scale projects.